# How to add shortcuts for installed apps in Kali Linux main menu?

Tags: kali-linux

My PC runs Kali Linux. After installing packages like Sublime, Google Chrome, Burpsuit Pro, and more, I can launch them only from the command line. I installed alacarte, and want to add shortcuts in the main menu. How do I add apps?

Comment: Yaa. I installed alacarte, but i don't know how to add items in it. I tried to browse files but it doesn't work for me. Can any one give me the reference to use the alacarte.

Comment: PS: You will find Linux answers quicker at https://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Packtpub](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/networking_and_servers/9781782168492/6/ch06lvl1sec46/adding-a-tool-to-the-main-menu-in-kali-2-x) tutorial illustrates the process.

Highlight a menu category, click on [New Item] at upper right, and a Launcher Properties dialog Box appears. Give the app a name.

Next, in the Command field, enter the full path to the installed app, or click on Browse and navigate until you find it.

If you want to, enter a brief phrase in the Comment field which will appear when you hover over that item as a Tool Tip.

Then, in the upper left corner of Launcher Properties,  click in the box and add or change the icon for the app.

Click [OK].

For details on the menu program itself, see [this Linux.com article](https://www.linux.com/news/alacarte-gnomes-long-overdue-menu-editor) or browse this [archived guide.](https://web.archive.org/web/20111008071926/http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/menustructure-1.html.en)

Comment: There seems to be no "new item" option in Kali 2021

Comment: Given that my answer was written in 2019, I am not surprised.

Answer (score 2):

## Kali 2022+

To edit the main menu in the the newer versions of Kali, you need to install a designated tool, called `alacarte`:

```sh
apt-get install alacarte
```

> Alacarte is a menu editor for GNOME using the freedesktop.org menu
> specification.

### How to add a new item

Open the tool called `main menu`:

[image: main menu tool]

This tool lets you easily edit the menu. To add a new item, add the `new item` button, highlighted in the screenshot.

Source: [official repo](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/alacarte) (on gnome.org)